# Feature Request: add Views/Votes next to Related questions

Tags: feature-request, information-display

Simple question. I have a small idea I'd like to suggest to develop on StackExchange. Who or where should this be directed? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Heeding Grace Notes answer below: here is my feature request:

In the "Related" section on the right of question pages, I'd like to see two smaller boxes stacked on or next to each other next to each related question.  The two boxes would simply be the views and votes on a question, shaded yellow if it has an answer.  This feature would reduce time digging though questions to find useful information as we could see immediately if it has an accepted answer. Also seeing the number of votes would indicate the content quality or provocation the question has elicited.   Thoughts?

Comment: Quora is always open to questions on increasing its relevancy

Comment: Right here. (and we need a down vote arrow for comments) ^^

Answer (score 2):

Ask here, on Meta Stack Overflow, with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and any additional tags that identify what kind of functionality you're proposing. This is the place for any questions about the Stack Exchange Network and its general engine.

As a warning, be aware that on these Meta sites, voting is done to indicate opinion of feature requests, as vote score influences the attention it gets from the team. So even if a question may be phrased well and is structurally sound, it may get downvoted if people disagree about it. Keep that in mind, so don't take any votes personally.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "idea I'd like to develop on StackExchange"

If it's a simple feature request or change that affects all the stackexchange sites, post it here as a new question.

If it's a new site, or a variation of stackexchange that wouldn't affect existing sites, you might try to contact team@stackoverflow.com directly, or you can develop the idea yourself using one of the many stackoverflow-like clones.

Comment: I hadn't had it mind to develop it myself, but that is sort of intriguing. Although I think it wouldn't be too hard to implement. Thanks.